# Python (Jinja2) variable inside a variable

Tags: python, variables, jinja2, ansible

I am trying to iterate over a dictionary in a Jinja2 template (in Ansible). One of the arrays or keys in the dictionary is 'abcd'

This `{{ item.value.abcd.port }}` works fine, but key 'abcd' varies in each dictionary.

I am looking to do something like below using a variable 'nginx_dir'.

```
{% set nginx_dir = item.value.keys().1 %}
{% set my_port = item.value.nginx_dir.port %}
```

Or without using a variable at all, something like this

```
{{ item.value.[item.value.keys().1].port }}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to use either of these to use a variable inside a variable.

```
{% set my_port = item.value.get(nginx_dir).port %}
{% set my_port = item.value[nginx_dir].port %}
```

I didn't wanted to hardcode my Jinja2 templates, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Could you show me how the variable `nginx_dir` looks like, how to set the value on it when it is dynamically changed.

Comment: The directory is `/opt/nginx/conf.d/something`. I had used a dictionary, and then looped over it. Sorry, it has been a while, I don’t have the exact code to show you.