# How to use a jinja2 variable as an arg in a call to salt function inside a jinja2 statement

Tags: python, yaml, jinja2, salt-stack

Here is what I am doing.

1. I am looping through pillar key values and assigning to variable shopt_option
2. If the string 'shopt_' is in the value of the variable shopt_option, it runs a nested if statement
3. Then inside a jinja2 encapsulated statement I need to set a variable to equal the output of a call to a salt function.
4. One of the args to that salt functions also needs to be a variable from the loop.
5. I have tried 2 hours worth of different ways to write this and what I will paste below of course is wrong syntax but helps to illustrate what I want to do as I know when referencing a variable inside a jinja2 statement you do not encapsulate it in double curly braces.
6. However being an arg inside of parentheses seems to screw up any way of using a jinja2 variable.
7. When looking below this is the line where it will need fixing, I am also open to other ways to write this as well

   ```
   {% set shopt_option_value = salt['pillar.get']('user_management:bash_configurations:global:bashrc:{{ shopt_option }}') %}
   ```

There is a ticket on stackoverflow where they nest a variable in a variable which come close, but doesnt working when inside a call to a salt function.
That stackoverflow url is [Python (Jinja2) variable inside a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32976700/python-jinja2-variable-inside-a-variable)

Here is the loop:

```
{# Loop through all global shopt option key names and set values accordingly #}
{% for shopt_option in salt['pillar.keys']('user_management:bash_configurations:global:bashrc') %}
  {% if 'shopt_' in shopt_option %}
    {% set shopt_option_value = salt['pillar.get']('user_management:bash_configurations:global:bashrc:{{ shopt_option }}') %}
    {% if shopt_option_value == 'True' %}
  shopt -s {{ shopt_option|replace("shopt_","") }}
    {% elif shopt_option_value == 'False' %}
  shopt -u {{ shopt_option|replace("shopt_","") }}
    {% elif shopt_option_value == 'default' %}
      # {{ shopt_option|replace("shopt_","") }} OS Default implied
    {% endif %}
      shopt_option_value is {{ shopt_option_value }} for debugging this
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the pillar yaml data structure snippet:

```
user_management:
  bash_configurations:
    global:
      bashrc:
        system_reserved_uid: 199
        system_reserved_umask: '077'
        non_system_reserved_umask: '077'
        shopt_autocd: default
        shopt_cdable_vars: default
        shopt_cdspell: False
        shopt_checkhash: default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to iterate through the pillars key names and or values.

Solution:

```
{%- for shopt_option_key in pillar['user_management']['bash_configurations']['global']['bashrc'] %}
```

seems is alternate way to say:

Original attempt:

```
{% for shopt_option in salt['pillar.keys']('user_management:bash_configurations:global:bashrc') %}
```

However in this way literal values are taken with single quotes and without the quotes in a jinja2 statement as you would expect it references the value of the jinja2 variable.

There were many other ways to solve this, I was looking at, this was just one of the way and maybe not the most elegant, so I would consider this a good solution (not the worst I found and not the best).

Here was the final solution:

```
{#- Loop through all global shopt option key names and set values accordingly #}
{%- for shopt_option_key in pillar['user_management']['bash_configurations']['global']['bashrc'] %}
  {%- set shopt_option_value = pillar['user_management']['bash_configurations']['global']['bashrc'][shopt_option_key] %}
  {%- if 'shopt_' in shopt_option_key %}
    {%- if shopt_option_value %}
      shopt -s {{ shopt_option_key|replace("shopt_","") }}
    {%- elif shopt_option_value == False %}
      shopt -u {{ shopt_option_key|replace("shopt_","") }}
    {%- elif shopt_option_value == 'default' %}
      # {{ shopt_option_key|replace("shopt_","") }} OS Default implied
    {%- endif %}
  {%- endif %}
{%- endfor %}
```

Some additional notes of improvement here:

1. The minus symbol here, {%- trimmed the leading white space so I would not have blank lines in the file this creates
2. In jinja2 if the value of the key was set to a Boolean, you can not use quotes around the 'True' or 'False' comparison, because it will treat the compared value as a string, I had to remove the quotes to treat it as a Boolean

Comment: I don't think setting one of your shopt fields to 'default' will work as you expect. With your solution, it will always enable options set to 'default' even if the system default is disabled because `shopt_option_value` will be set to 'default' and `if 'default'` evaluates to `True`

Comment: if the pillar shopt_option was defined, {% if  shopt_option %} would evaluate to true, {% if shopt_option == True %} would evaluate to true, but it seems that {% if shopt_option == 'True' %} treats it as the string True not the boolean True

Comment: Ah, you may have a point on this line {%- if shopt_option_value %}, any defined pillar would evaluate to true, so the default if statement would never get hit, I probably edited that line last week, I will see what I settled on and post the correction, for the sake of perfection. Thanks for the catch.